# Need help in this field theory question which is related to splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

This question was asked in a quaifying exam for which I am preparing.

> Let F $\subseteq \mathbb{C}$be the splitting field of $x^{7}-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$and $z=e^{2\pi i /7}$, aprimitive 7th root of unity.

Then Find $[F:\mathbb{Q(z)}]$=a and $[F:\mathbb{Q}({2}^{1/7})]=b$

I have studied Field Theory from Thomas Hungerford and couldn't try any problems due to lack of time.So, I am not able solve it.

splitting field is a field in which polynomial splits completely ie all its roots are linear and $({2}^{1/7})$ is one of the roots. But I am not able to use them in my question .

Can you please help on how to tackle the problem. I know this is happening due to lack of problem solving.

Thanks!!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3861159/finding-the-mathbbq-automorphisms-of-the-splitting-field-of-xp-2-over/3861352#3861352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{2}):\mathbb{Q}|=7$ and $|\mathbb{Q}(z):\mathbb{Q}|=\phi(7)=6$. Hence $$|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{2},z):\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{2},z):\mathbb{Q}(z)||\mathbb{Q}(z):\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{2},z):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{2})||\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{2}):\mathbb{Q}|\Rightarrow$$

$$\Rightarrow |\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{2},z):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{2})|\cdot 6=|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{2},z):\mathbb{Q}(z)|\cdot 7\Rightarrow $$

$|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{2},z):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{2})|=7$ and $|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[7]{2},z):\mathbb{Q}(z)|=6$

Comment: Can you please explain why [Q(z): Q] =6 in first line of your answer?

Comment: This is a standard fact for $n-$th roots of unity. $z=\zeta_7$ is a root of $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ which is irreducible of degree $6$